# Customize CEF build and remove unused Chromium features

Tags: windows, chromium-embedded

I need to compile cef3 with minimal features. I don't need print/media/devtools etc features. How can I disable it during the build? Using cef3 without disabling other features consumes ~100MB memory for single instance so it's not usable if the application is intended for multiple instances.

I want to reduce the memory usage of cef3.

I looked into BUILD.gn and gni files but could not locate a place for disabling features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it will be easy to disable the mentioned features. But here are a few things you can try:

1) run `python automate-git.py --help` to give you a list of options on how to make the build run faster

2) check the file `cef\tests\shared\common\client_switches.cc` for some of the supported command line switches. I'll quote from that file:

```
// CEF and Chromium support a wide range of command-line switches. This file
// only contains command-line switches specific to the cefclient application.
// View CEF/Chromium documentation or search for *_switches.cc files in the
// Chromium source code to identify other existing command-line switches.
// Below is a partial listing of relevant *_switches.cc files:
//   base/base_switches.cc
//   cef/libcef/common/cef_switches.cc
//   chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc (not all apply)
//   content/public/common/content_switches.cc
```

3) see [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) - You'll find many useful CLI switches like `--disable-extensions`

4) I also found [Electron - Supported Chrome Command Line Switches](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/chrome-command-line-switches) which mentions `--disable-http2` and according to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42435786/how-to-disable-http-2-in-chrome-or-chromium) it actually works.

P.S. I don't think you can easily remove features during the build process.