# force start using only HTTP/1.1

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension for chrome and for some reason I need to disable the following  transport protocols: `HTTP/2`, `SPDY`, `QUIC`, basically only  `HTTP/1.1` should be allowed.

Theoretically I can modify  to soft-disable `HTTP/2` by changing HTTP "Connection:" request header.
Using “**Connection: keep-alive**” prevents “**Connection: upgrade**”. but this method is not guaranteed for "https" URIs, because `HTTP/2` over TLS uses the "h2" protocol identifier.

Could I somehow to  force start using only `HTTP/1.1`?
If on, is there a method in the browser API that can closes idle sockets  as it does a button on this page `chrome://net-internals/#sockets`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42435786/how-to-disable-http-2-in-chrome-or-chromium might work

Comment: Have you tried to use an AJAX request and host this on a separate domain with a separate HTTPS certificate?